# How to get count with pagination in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

The query that I'm using for getting total count with pagination is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT r.*, ROWNUM RNUM, COUNT(*) OVER () RESULT_COUNT 
      FROM (SELECT t0.ABC_SEQ_ID AS c0, t0.FIRST_NAME, t1.SCORE
            FROM ABC t0, XYZ t1
            WHERE (t0.XYZ_ID = 751) 
            AND t0.XYZ_ID = t1.XYZ_ID 
            ORDER BY t0.RANK ASC) R)
WHERE RNUM between 1 and 15
```

Obviously it won't return any row when pagination values are out of range (greater than the data size). The question is how do I get total count with pagination using a single query when the pagination values are out of range? Is it possible using a single query?

**EDIT**

For example:

Total rows for a particular criteria are 20. And pagination values are from 25 to 30. Now want to send the total row count to the client but this query won't return any row. How do I tackle this case.

Comment: @HadhimR: Why you want count when the total rows are 20,for the first iteration you get to know that the total count is 20 ,then why you want to fetch 25 to 30 rows?

Comment: @GauravSoni: If I set value of `RNUM` from `25` to `30`, there is no first iteration. Then how would I know what is the total row count? This is a special case that needs to be handled...

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH R AS
(SELECT r.*, ROWNUM RNUM, COUNT(*) OVER () RESULT_COUNT 
      FROM (SELECT t0.ABC_SEQ_ID AS c0, t0.FIRST_NAME, t1.SCORE
             FROM ABC t0, XYZ t1
            WHERE (t0.XYZ_ID = 751) 
             AND t0.XYZ_ID = t1.XYZ_ID 
           ORDER BY t0.RANK ASC
           ) 
 )
 SELECT c0,FIRST_NAME,score,RESULT_COUNT  FROM R WHERE RNUM between 25 and 30
 UNION 
 SELECT null,null,null
       ,NVL((SELECT result_count FROM R WHERE ROWNUM=1),0) result_count
 FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM R WHERE RNUM between 25 and 30);
```

This query is not optimized ,but still it will gave you the count ,if the condition are not matched  i.e 0

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a **special** case, why not handle it **special** if you need?

Leave your query as it is, but if no row is returned, query again with `RNUM between 1 and 1`.

You can use the same view/function/prepared statement for this, and the performance of your original query is not affected.